# Permission denied when doing Postfix ubuntu tutorial

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta, mail-server

Im working on this tutorial Postfix mail server. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

When i run the command. 
su - fmaster
mail

I get the error. 
Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/fmaster: Permission denied
No mail for fmaster

also i sign in as fmaster. 
terminal -> mail.

/var/mail/fmaster: Permission denied
No mail for fmaster

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
           sudo touch /var/mail/$USER
           sudo chown $USER:mail /var/mail/$USER
           sudo chmod o-r /var/mail/$USER
           sudo chmod g+rw /var/mail/$USER
```

Comment: you can replace last two lines with:
    sudo chmod 660 /var/mail/$USER